# Error estimation for numerical differentiation without knowing higher order derivation terms.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I recently [posted a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699551/finding-an-error-estimation-for-central-difference-formula) about computing error estimation of central difference formula:

$$f'(x)\approx D(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$

It turns out that:

$$f'(x)=D(x)-\frac{h^2}{3}f'''(x)+\dots$$

However, in my case, I can't symbolically calculate $f'''(x)$. **So my question is, is there any other, even less accurate, method to calculate $\epsilon$ which will always hold**:

$$\epsilon\ge|D(x) - f'(x)|$$

Why I need it? I, just for fun, wrote a really simple program for symbolic differentiation and need to check that my output seems to be correct.

Lets say that $\hat{f'}(x)$ is symbolic differentation computed by my program. Sometimes $\hat{f'}(x)=f'(x)$, sometimes $\hat{f'}(x)\ne f'(x)$. I want to check that $\hat{f'(x)}$ is close to $D(x)$ to validate my program. Unfortunatelly, it's vary hard to algorithmically say what "close to" mean.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why can you not just calculate the quantity $D(x) - f'(x)$ explicitly for a series of test points? Of course, this will not *guarantee* that your bound will always be smaller than $\varepsilon$ but it should suffice for practical purposes. In general, the error bound that you derived doesn't look particularly helpful if $f'''$ is unknown or you don't know how to bound it explicitly. As it is an a-priori bound, it is more useful in the sense of knowing the rate at which the error goes to zero rather than for practical purposes.

Comment: $f(x)$ is generated on the fly using QuickCheck. I don't want to compute it explicitly. I'd rather want to calculate symbolic differentation using my program and compare it to it's estimated numeric differentation. Problem is that $|f'(x)-D(x)|$ could be very varying.

Comment: I suppose you could always compute $f'''$ numerically for a series of points and take their maximum to approximate the upper bound. Either way, you're going to **have to compute something extra** if you want the error bound and $f'''$ is unknown - nothing in life is free!

Comment: It's not a cost question. I thought that calculating $f'''(x)$ using central difference formula implies the same problem as calculating $D(x)$ (it's inaccurate).

Comment: Not necessarily, there will of course be an error in the calculation of $f'''$ as in the difference $|f'(x)-D(x)|$ but for small enough $h$, this becomes so close to the value $f'''$ that we don't care. Remember: $|f'(x) - D(x)|$ is as small as you desire, $\sup_x |f'''(x)|$ is constant. Thus as long as you use a suitably small step-size, the error in this approximation would be something like $\frac{h^2}{3}(\sup_x |f'''(x)| + \varepsilon)$ where $\varepsilon > 0$ is the numerical error in approximating $f'''$. Clearly, here, the main contribution to the bound is from $h^2$.